# How to write java program to push email

Tags: java, postfix-mta

Hi I have postfix running on my Mail Server. I want the following functionality using java program

Whenever a new mail comes i came to know using postfix. but I want a java program which can read this newly coming email.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: The answer depends a bit on your environment. Is this a UNIX Mailbox, or can the mail account be accessed via POP3? IMAP, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) and [mail support](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/spring-integration-reference.html#mail).